# Serverless access to SFProRole is denied by IAM

Tags: amazon-iam, serverless-framework

The SFProSetup stack was deleted by mistake. This deleted an IAM role needed for `serverless deploy`

So I redeployed the template under a new name but the following error message still occurs when deploying my service.

> Error: {"errorMessage":"Your AWS credential for deployment profile default is configured to use the IAM role arn:aws:iam::730609332320:role/SFProRole, but access to that role was denied by IAM. - Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue - NVB2DG9Q46SQ"}

I have one aws profile and have been deploying successfully before this.

Answer (score 0):

I redeployed the template with the following command

> aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ~/Desktop/serverless_setup.yml --stack-name SFProSetup --region us-east-1 --profile default --parameter-overrides OrgId=xyz123 ProfileName=default --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM

A series of steps led me to find that the stack must be deployed in `us-east-1` because that's the only region the Reporter component can talk to. `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` was necessary because the template creates an AWS role with a capability. And finally, I noticed a parameter for OrgId was used in the original stack creation, so I added it to the paramter overrides in the command. I'm guessing this is my id in serverless `OrgId=xyz123`